# Python 3.7 OpenCV - Slow processing

Tags: python, performance, opencv

i'm trying to take pictures with OpenCV 4.4.0.40 and only save them if a switch, read by an Arduino, is press.

So far everything work, but it's super slow, it take about 15 seconds for the `Switch` value to change.

```
Arduino = SerialObject()

if os.path.exists(PathCouleur) and os.path.exists(PathGris):

Images = cv2.VideoCapture(Camera)
Images.set(3, 1920)
Images.set(4, 1080)
Images.set(10, Brightness)

Compte = 0

SwitchNumero = 0

while True:

    Sucess, Video = Images.read()
    cv2.imshow("Camera", Video)
    Video = cv2.resize(Video, (Largeur, Hauteur))

    Switch = Arduino.getData()
    
    try:
        if Switch[0] == "1":
            blur = cv2.Laplacian(Video, cv2.CV_64F).var()

            if blur < MinBlur:
                cv2.imwrite(PathCouleur + ".png", Video)
                cv2.imwrite(PathGris + ".png", cv2.cvtColor(Video, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
                Compte += 1
    
    except IndexError as err:
        pass

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break

Images.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

else:
    print("Erreur, aucun Path")
```

the saved images width are 640 and the height is 480 and the showimage is 1920x1080 but even without the showimage it's slow.

Can someone help me optimize this code please?

Comment: the `sleep()` is the issue. NEVER sleep while reading from a VideoCapture object

Comment: No i've already tried without. Actually the code i have right now don't have the sleep in it, i just didn't remove it on this one (my bad), but thank trying to help.

Comment: use [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) to see what is taking most of the time

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this snippet of code is responsible for the delay, since you have two major calls that depend on external devices to respond (the OpenCV calls and `Arduino.getData()`).

> ```
> Sucess, Video = Images.read()
> cv2.imshow("Camera", Video)
> Video = cv2.resize(Video, (Largeur, Hauteur))
>
> Switch = Arduino.getData()
> ```

One solution that comes to mind is to use the multithreading lib and separate the `Arduino.getData()` call from the main loop cycle and use it in a separate class to run in the background (you should use a sleep on the secondary thread, something like 50 or 100ms delay).

That way you should have a better response on the Switch event, when it tries to read the value on the main loop.

Comment: thanks, that sound great, i'll do more research and see if it work :)

Answer (score -1):

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

use cv2.CAP_DSHOW it will improve the loading time of camera becasue it wil give you video feed directly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31943006)